# How to extract part of changes made in a branch into a separate branch

Tags: git

I have a branch `feature/a` that contains all changes that I made while working on feature `a`. It contains both refactoring changes, and functional changes. It came out to be a big pull request, so I now want to extract the refactoring part into a separate branch `feature/a-refactoring`, make a pull request for that, and then have a separate pull request with functional changes in `feature/a-functional`.

I thought about solving this using the following steps:

1. Go into `feature/a`
2. create a new branch `git checkout -b feature/a-refactoring`
3. do `git reset <commit-before-my-changes>`
4. pick refactoring changes using GUI Git tool (for easier hunk selection)
5. make that into a single commit, and do a pull request.

But the problem is, I have merged master two times during `feature/a` development. And now if I do step 3, it will contain changes that have been made to master as well, and I would need to merge master into it again, which I don't want to do since there is a lot of merge conflicts.

How to better solve this? Can I move all my commits "to the top" in my branch, after merges, so that I can do `git reset` without having to solve merge conflicts?

Is there maybe a feature in some GUI Git client that would allow me to do this?

NOTE: It's important to understand that there are like 60 commits and most of them contain both refactoring AND functional changes. I want to diff them against the current master, pick only those changes that are related to refactoring (by hand) and then create a separate pull request out of that.

Comment: What is `git ck`? Please [edit] and expand your personal alias.

Comment: seemed pretty self-explaintory, ck being checkout, ok I expanded it

Answer (score 0):

If you actually haven't started doing it then start by merging with `master` a last time, so you do not miss anything:

```
git checkout feature/a
git merge master # or whatever branch your upstream is
```

Now, let's start with the magic

```
git checkout -b feature/a-refactoring
git reset --soft master
# at this point, feel free to leave only the refactoring changes on your working tree.... then git add them commit
git add .
git commit -m "Only refactoring work is here"
```

After we do that, we can do the second part of the magic:

```
git checkout feature/a
git reset --soft feature/a-refactor
git commit -m "The non-refactoring part"
```

The non-so-good thing is that you lose history of the work that you did to develop `A`, of course, but I think you are already aware of it.

Comment: It's important to understand that there are like 60 commits and most of them contain both refactoring AND functional changes. I want to diff them against the current master, pick only those changes that are related to refactoring (by hand) and then create a separate pull request out of that. Your answer is for those cases where refactoring & functional changes are clearly separated.

Comment: There you go!!!